# Why is compiled java not forwards compatible

Tags: java, jvm, bytecode

Unless I am misunderstanding how the JVM works, isn't Java bytecode sort of the same as compiled C except that it runs on the JVM as opposed to the OS (The JVM acting as the OS)?

If so, doesn't that mean that newer jars should be able to run on whatever version of the JVM I want?

Or is there some sort of difference in the actual bytecode instructions between Java versions that don't exist in things like C?

Comment: "newer jars should be able to run on whatever version of the JVM I want" Wouldn't that be forward-compatible?

Comment: @PaulBellora unless I am mistaken, forward-compatible means that old jars can still run on the new jvm, no?

Comment: if I code and compile a program using C++14, you would say it is backwards compatible as it will run on any system, regardless of version (I think)

Comment: There is a term [JNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't forward compatible because that would mean that it wouldn't be possible to introcuce new byte-codes.

When a new version of java introduced a new bytecode, naturally, older versions of the VM wouldn't be able to interpret that bytecode.

This means that java can not be forward compatible as it maintains an evolving set of (native) commands.

This is different to C/C++. A compiler for such a language generates byte-code for *the exact processor* you are targeting. The command set for a processor will not change, it is static. Thus, when compiling C for a specific CPU, every version of the C/C++ standard will compile and run, as long as there is an instruction that corresponds to the operation needed.

---

Edit: This problem can be seen in C/C++, too, when you look closely. For example the header `<cstdint>` introduces **optional** types e.g. `int64_t`. This for the reason of forward compatibility. Older chips might not be able to handle 64-bit integer types, thus to maintain forward compatibility for those, the standard makes them optional to declare.

Comment: So the JVM is more relatable to the processor, not the OS?

Comment: @Epicblood, yes. It executes bytecode, the same thing a processor does. But most processors share a common set of instructions (x86 for example), which is why the JVM doesn't have to target each processor specifically. It would be faster and more efficient to do that, though

Answer (score 2):

No. There are usually actual (incompatible) differences introduced to support new features (and there's *always* a version number). Byte-code is backwards compatible in the sense that byte code compiled by an older compiler can be invoked (and linked) by *newer* environments (backwards). It isn't *forwards* compatible, which is what you've actually asked about. Regardless, you can examine the instruction mnemonics with `javap -v` and see the version.

Also, from your question, (as a *contrived* example) code compiled with `gcc` to target an Intel pentium with `-march=586` (probably) won't run on a `486` or a `386` (in contrast with `-mtune`).

Comment: In your example, does the incompatibility come from the language level? or because the architecture of the pentium is different? Because from my understanding (could be wrong) but lets say I code something and compile it with c++14, it will run on whatever version of C++ as the actual instructions are the same.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen In the form of byte-code? I think it (mostly) works. I can think of a few changes that weren't backwards compatible (but using a jar file with a sane interface, that doesn't do any byte-code manipulation usually works).

Comment: @Epicblood The architecture of the JVM *can* (and **sometimes** *does*) change between releases.

Comment: @Tim How so? The only backwards incompatible change I know of is the removal of ACC_SUPER, and that's an incredibly obscure feature only introduced to work around an early compiler bug.

Comment: @Epicblood: “it will run on whatever version of C++” makes no sense. Your compiled C++ code doesn’t run on a `C++` version. It runs on a *CPU* for which you compiled and will not run on an older CPU. Similarly, Java source code is compiled to something which runs on a *JVM* you have targeted. That JVM has nothing to do with a source code version, though JVM and java compiler are usually shipped together.